# How to search books by author name?

Tags: php, api, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm using the [Amazon Product Advertising Ruby API (amazon-ecs)](https://rubygems.org/gems/amazon-ecs/versions/2.3.1) library. I have a list of some "vips" and I need to know if they are also the book's writer. So I need to know how can I do a `ItemSearch` by author name.

```
$response = $amazonEcs->returnType(1)
                  ->responseGroup('Large')
                  ->optionalParameters(array('ItemPage' => 1))
                  ->category('Books')
                  ->page(1)
                  ->author($author_name);
```

How would I accomplish this?